# Should the same connection be injected into multiple repositories or a new connection opened in each method called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have a view that requires information to be filled from multiple repositories in my system.

```
var employee = employeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(20);
var notes = notesRepository.GetNotes();
```

I'm using ADO.NET for data access. Should each repository take in a connection as a parameter?

```
using(var connection = dbFactory.GetConnection())
{    
    var employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository(connection);
    var notesRepository = new NotesRepository(connection);
}
```

Or, should each Get method, open up and close the connection within the method? I've timed execution, and using a single connection passed around is faster. Not by a ton. I'm more concerned about having the correct approach right now.

Also what effect on the db does it mean to keep opening and closing connections?

Comment: I think a common approach to this is to create a connection per unit of work. If multiple DB calls are necessary for one operation, they'll share the connection. If only one DB call is necessary for a unit of work, then you'll use a connection for that one call. Google `unit of work pattern` and check out the first two links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.NET uses a [`connection pooling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) to increase performance (this is true for SQL server, checkout with your database provider documentation whether it supports connection pooling). So when you are creating a new SqlConnection you are actually not opening a physical connection to the database. You are simply drawing an existing connection from the connection pool. And when you are calling .Dispose on an existing connection you are actually not closing the physical connection to the database. You are simply returning this connection to the connection pool so that it can be reused.

So you could safely write the following code everytime you want to send a query to your database:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCOmmand())
{
    // no, you are not opening a real connection here, you are just drawing one from the pool
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ....";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
} // No, you are not closing the connection here, you are simply returning it to the pool
```

So basically if your ADO.NET provider supports connection pooling (which normally all respected providers should), you don't need to be storing any references to SQL connections. Simply call the constructor and pass the connection string. As a consequence the connection string is all you need.

Remark: The connection pooling is done per AppDomain and per connection string. This means that if you have 2 different connection strings connecting to the same database and you are passing those 2 connection strings to different instances of SQL connections you will get a connection pool per connection string (i.e. 2 pools).

Comment: And that is DB independent? We are using SQLBase(not by choice) which just released their fully managed .NET data provider. Pooling still takes place?

Comment: I have no idea what SQLBase is. You should read their documentation and whether the ADO.NET provider you are using supports connection pooling.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov What if I need different methods of different repositories to execute within the same transaction? Should I inject the transaction object `Conexion.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)` into those repositories?